# Using generics to generate documentation about newtype

Tags: haskell, newtype

I have a Haskell project, which uses a few `newtypes`.
I would like to export a table of these, so I can include it in my documentation (not-haddock), as a markdown table for instance. I'm not familiar with this, but from reading around, my plan was to use `Generics/Data.Data`, to create some functions that broadly look as follows:

```
data MyRowRepresentation = MyRowRepresentation
                                String -- Name of the newtype
                                String -- Name of the type its wrapping

toDocRow :: (Generic a, HasDatatypeInfo a) -> (Proxy a) -> MyRowRepresentation
toDocRow = <the part I'm struggling with>

newtype MyType0 = MyType0 Int16
newtype MyType1 = MyType0 Int8
newtype MyType2 = MyType0 Int32
newtype MyType3 = MyType0 Word8

main = do
  let table = [
        toDocRow (Proxy::MyType0),
        toDocRow (Proxy::MyType1),
        toDocRow (Proxy::MyType2),
        toDocRow (Proxy::MyType3),
        ]
  -- Do something to write `table` to disk.
```

However, I am struggling to understand how `Generics/Data.Data` interacts with Constructors. Its my first time using area of Haskell, so I tried the following code, just to see how it worked:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
module TmpTmpExport where

import RIO
import RIO.List.Partial (head)
import Text.Show.Pretty
import Data.String.Conversions    (cs)
import Data.Data


newtype MyNewType = MyNewType Integer
  deriving (Show)
  deriving (Data, Typeable)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  traceM $ cs $ "INSTANCE: "            ++ (show $ dataTypeConstrs $ dataTypeOf $ (MyNewType 0))
  traceM $ cs $ "INSTANCE constrType: " ++ (show $ constrType $ head $ dataTypeConstrs $ dataTypeOf $ (MyNewType 0))
  traceM $ cs $ "INSTANCE constrType: " ++ (show $ dataTypeConstrs $ constrType $ head $ dataTypeConstrs $ dataTypeOf $ (MyNewType 0))
  traceM $ cs $ "INSTANCE constrType: " ++ (show $ (fmap showConstr) $ dataTypeConstrs $ constrType $ head $ dataTypeConstrs $ dataTypeOf $ (MyNewType 0))
  traceM $ cs $ "INSTANCE constrType: " ++ (show $ dataTypeConstrs $ constrType $ head $ dataTypeConstrs $ constrType $ head $ dataTypeConstrs $ constrType $ head $ dataTypeConstrs $ dataTypeOf $ (MyNewType 0))



  return ()
```

Which gives the following output:

```
INSTANCE: [MyNewType]
INSTANCE constrType: DataType {tycon = "MyNewType", datarep = AlgRep [MyNewType]}
INSTANCE constrType: [MyNewType]
INSTANCE constrType: ["MyNewType"]
INSTANCE constrType: [MyNewType]
```

I don't think I'm a million miles away, but from reading the documentation for `Data.Data`,  and trying various functions out, I couldn't work out how to "get inside" the newtype using `dataTypeConstrs` and `constrType`, so that I can create `table` with rows like:

```
table = [
    (MyRowRepresentation "Type0" "Int16"),
    (MyRowRepresentation "Type1" "Int8")
    (MyRowRepresentation "Type2" "Int32")
    (MyRowRepresentation "Type3" "Word8")
]
```

Have I conceptually missed something about the difference between `newtype` and `data`, is this possible to do with `Data.Data`, or should I be looking at a different tool/library?

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely do this with `GHC.Generics`. I'm less familiar with `Data.Data`.

The easy way, using [`coercible-utils >= 0.1.0`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/coercible-utils):

```hs
import CoercibleUtils.Newtype

toDocRow :: forall a o proxy. (Newtype a o, Typeable a, Typeable o) => proxy a -> MyRowRepresentation
toDocRow _ = MyRowRepresentation
  (show (typeRep (Proxy :: Proxy a)))
  (show (typeRep (Proxy :: Proxy o)))
```

This version insists on an actual newtype, rather than a single-constructor datatype.

---

Here's how you could roll your own with `Generic`. The instances will be for `M1` and `K1`. My first thought is that you should use `Typeable` on the very outside (before you open up the generic representation) to get the newtype name, then use a boring instance to ignore `M1` layers, then use Typeable again for `K1` to get the wrapped type info. On the outside you could instead use the metadata attached to the outermost `M1`, but that seems much more awkward.

Note that the below can be cleaned up a bit using `TypeApplications` instead of proxy passing.

```hs
{-# language DeriveGeneric, FlexibleContexts, ScopedTypeVariables, KindSignatures #-}
import GHC.Generics
import Data.Typeable
import Data.Int
import Data.Word
import Data.Kind (Type)

data MyRowRepresentation = MyRowRepresentation
  String -- Name of the newtype
  String -- Name of the type its wrapping
  deriving Show

toDocRow :: forall a proxy. (Generic a, Typeable a, Grump (Rep a)) => proxy a -> MyRowRepresentation
toDocRow _ = MyRowRepresentation
  (show (typeRep (Proxy :: Proxy a)))
  (show $ grump (Proxy :: Proxy (Rep a)))

class Grump (f :: Type -> Type) where
  grump :: Proxy f -> TypeRep

instance Grump f => Grump (M1 i c f) where
  grump _ = grump (Proxy :: Proxy f)

instance Typeable c => Grump (K1 i c) where
  grump _ = typeRep (Proxy :: Proxy c)

newtype MyType0 = MyType0 Int16
  deriving Generic
newtype MyType1 = MyType1 Int8
  deriving Generic
newtype MyType2 = MyType2 Int32
  deriving Generic
newtype MyType3 = MyType3 Word8
  deriving Generic

main = do
  let table = [
        toDocRow (Proxy:: Proxy MyType0),
        toDocRow (Proxy:: Proxy MyType1),
        toDocRow (Proxy:: Proxy MyType2),
        toDocRow (Proxy:: Proxy MyType3)
        ]
  print table
```

Comment: Thankyou @dfeuer - this is exactly what I was looking to do. I'll study it further to understand exactly what is going on!

Comment: @user2633351, let me know if you need any further help with that. The definition of the `Newtype` class and its instance are actually fairly straightforward. (The same cannot be said, unfortunately, for the `Similar` class in the same module; maybe you can help simplify that!)